# Choosing appropriate lag length when AIC, BIC keep falling?

Tags: r, time-series, granger-causality, pandas

I'm trying to test for g-causality between a number of variables and of course I have to specify a lag length there.

So, till now my approach was to test a number of lags simply (say, 1 to 30) and then look where the "cliff" was. Typically I saw a pretty drastic drop from, say, 0.995 with p=6 to 1.3^-5 at p=7 (and then slowly towards zero).

Now, with this approach, it's pretty easy to tell, that the actual lag is probably 7. However, I just tested some other variables that definitely do *not* cause each other, yet I got the same pattern (though with unusual, but not impossible lags).

Then I read further and learned that AIC and BIC values for each lag could be an indicator for appropriate lags. However, they keep falling. Pretty much forever, thus being absolutely useless.

BTW: I'm working with a point process. That is, a bunch of nodes fire once in while and propagate this to (some) adjacent nodes, my job is to find the edges, lag length corresponds to edge distance. At the moment, I'm using Pandas stats.var.VAR module, but R would be an option too.

EDIT:

Those are the AICs for two variables that should have a lag of roughly 12. As suggested in the comments, those maybe the negative values, which would mean, that 8 is the "proper" lag according to AIC, that's closer than before, but still not exactly good.

And sorry for the abysmal formatting.

1. 14798635.842416
2. 14798605.836719
3. 14798608.706591
4. 14798617.388293
5. 14798626.439701
6. 14798638.423804
7. 14798670.825731
8. 14798699.214412
9. 14782367.519411
10. 14746502.385220
11. 14716685.877876
12. 14714826.173971
13. 14714870.357522
14. 14714957.323165
15. 14715051.674466
16. 14715148.077736
17. 14714989.450383
18. 14713741.670316
19. 14710852.667756
20. 14708195.634576

Comment: Could it be that you are actually getting the *negative* of AIC or BIC? Then it would make sense that it keeps falling at large lags (as the model is getting too rich, and more so with every lag).

Comment: Updated my post. But, as mentioned above, those values are still not quite there. Maybe I'm expecting too much precision?

Comment: Well, one example is not enough to conclude anything about precision. If you tried at least a hundred or a thousand cases, that would be more reliable. It is better to use artificial data that you know for sure to have a certain lag, not "a lag of roughly 12". You could also try calculating the AIC manually (shouldn't be hard).

Comment: Those are simulated data. The problem is, that due to the unprecise nature of the real system, I had to simulate unprecise data. I tested some more pairs, and some work pretty well, some not at all; but there's a second peak at the appropriate lag, I'm working on isolating this.

Comment: To see whether AIC works the way it should, you need idealistic examples, not "unprecise data". Once you have figured out whether negative AIC is indeed reported as AIC, the question of this post will be answered. Meanwhile, you cannot expect AIC to guess "right" every time given real world data where models are just rough approximations of the true data generating processes.

Comment: The unprecision is within 1s, that is, one lag order. Also there are some unrelated signals, but I can't just throw them out, because that's exactly the problem I have to solve.

Comment: So is there still a concrete question left for this post, or is it something else that deserves a new post?

Comment: Well, the question still is, how I can find a good lag. I'm not sure if "the best AIC is obviously wrong, so I chose the next one" is  a valid answer. Especially since it's supposed to be automated.

Comment: **1.** AIC is not "wrong", it has nice properties that have been known for a while now. It suits well for automated model selection. Of course, if all the candidate models are really bad, AIC will not do any magic and will just select the best of the really bad models (still bad). But that is not the problem of AIC – rather the problem of the user that supplies the candidate models. **2.** If the problem is with software implementation, perhaps you should do your own implementation or change software. "vars" package in R works fine as far as I know.